# How to inject an unique instance of a service in a dynamically created component?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-dynamic-components

I have a `BaseComponent` and other components that extend that, like a `WidgetComponent` for example.

I create the `WidgetComponents` dynamically, using `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

The `BaseComponent` is responsible for making http requests so the extended components have access to the response through a public property that holds an `Observable`. It uses the `SomeService` service to make those requests.

The `BaseComponent` is declared in a lazy-loaded module.

The problem is, every time the `BaseComponent` makes a request, each extended class gets the response because I think I'm not using a unique instance of the service.

So my question is, how can I use a different instance of `SomeService` each time I dynamically create a `WidgetComponent`?

This is my setup:

// BaseComponent.ts

```js
import { InjectorService } from '@services/utils/injector.service';
import { SomeService } from '@services/some.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'base-widget',
    templateUrl: './base-widget.component.html'
})
export class BaseWidgetComponent {
    response$!: Observable<any>;
    someService: SomeService;

    constructor() {
        const injector = InjectorService.getInjector();
        this.someService = injector.get(SomeService);

        this.response$ = this.someService.getData();
    }
}
```

// WidgetComponent

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'widget',
    templateUrl: './widget.component.html'
})
export class WidgetComponent extends BaseWidget implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.response$.subscribe(console.log);
    }
}
```

// SomeService

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) // I think this is not the correct way of providing it.
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getData() {
        return this.http.get('url');
    }
}
```

// InjectorService

```js
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

export class InjectorService {
    private static injector: Injector;

    static setInjector(injector: Injector) {
        InjectorService.injector = injector;
    }

    static getInjector(): Injector {
        return InjectorService.injector;
    }
}
```

// main.ts

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { InjectorService } from '@services/utils/injector.service';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const moduleRef = await platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
        InjectorService.setInjector(moduleRef.injector);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Comment: A component can have its own unique instance of a service by adding that service to the component's `providers` array. See the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components). "Providing a service in the component limits the service only to that component and its descendants. Other components in the same module can’t access it."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So in that case, every new instance of the component would have its own unique service instance? Also, I forgot to mention an important detail. The component is declared in a lazy-loaded module. I tried providing the service in the component but I got a "null injection" error.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to use Inheritance where Angular is better used with Composition.
Long story short, why don't you export your code in BaseWidgetComponent in another Service ? (and use Angular DI to get this service in your components)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your service in `providers` section of the `@Component` declaraction

```
@Component({
    selector: 'base-widget',
    templateUrl: './base-widget.component.html',
    providers:[SomeService]
    
})
```

This way every instance of component will get unique instane of `SomeService`

Comment: Does this work when the component is part of a lazy-loaded module?

Comment: Yes it does. My only doubt is that if `providers`  will work correctly on the base class or it has to be included into every component that inherits it. As mentioned before, Angular is better with composition that inheritence thus never had to tried that.